# Adding custom method to WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to the WebAPI and I got stuck in a problem. I am using API controller which contains two `Get` methods. One is used for `GetAll` while other retrieves data on the basis of ID. Now what I want to do is to implement another get method which takes `string` and returns records. I have made that method and call that it does not work as my route was default API route which was like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
```

When I added a new route to call my custom `GetMethod`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Custom", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
```

I was able to call my custom `GetMethod` but now I lose the restful method with id parameters. How can I use both methods?

Comment: I have also try using Attribute routing like [Route(api/controllername/action)] on the top of the method but it still did not works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your second route only and call as

```
api/customer/get/1
api/customer/getall/
api/customer/getmethod/one
```

In the above, customer is the *controller* name. You have to replace with yours.

Please check whether you have the routes in the **webapiconfig.cs** file. Please [refer](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api) this article for more help.

Comment: I have tried this i was able to call api/customer/get/1 and api/customer/getall but for api/customer/getmethod/one i am getting error "{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'CustomersProject.Models.BaseModel Get(Int32)' in 'CustomersProject.Controllers.BaseController`2[CustomersProject.Models.Customer,CustomersProject.ApiModel.CustomerApiModel]'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}"

Comment: You may need to have one more route similar to the second one, but have a constraint to say id is of type 'string'. If both the methods do the same thing, a better design would be to have only one GET and the client convert the string id to int id and call the single get method.

Comment: The problem is that when i added a route to the web.config i have to place that route above the default route Then i lost the restful services i want the id method to be called as api/customer/1 ,the getall method to be api/customer and my method for search as customer/get/kashif   where kashif is the name to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Better not to change routes.
You can use Action Name to differentiate the calls and can add more functions. Take a look at this answer:
[How to add custom methods to ASP.NET WebAPI controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843264/how-to-add-custom-methods-to-asp-net-webapi-controller)

Comment: i had changed my routes to defaults and make my methods look like this... [ActionName("search")] 
        [HttpGet]
        public virtual BaseModel Get(string name) 
        {
            return new BaseModel() { Success = true };
        }   and call like this api/customer/search but it still not works