# unable to call web api using custom methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I followed some answers but getting the following error on postman

`{
  "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}`

these were the links i followed

[Web API route to action name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661946/web-api-route-to-action-name)

[How to add custom methods to ASP.NET WebAPI controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843264/how-to-add-custom-methods-to-asp-net-webapi-controller)

currently setup is like the one as sky-dev has described

[Custom method names in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569270/custom-method-names-in-asp-net-web-api)

**Updated with code**

webapiconfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        //config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        //// Web API routes
        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //    name: "DefaultApi",
        //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        //);
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "api/{controller}/{action}");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ApiWithActionName",routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });

    }
```

defaultcontroller.cs

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    public IEnumerable<CategoryDTO> Category()
    {
        IEnumerable<CategoryDTO> List = from tr in db.Categories
                                                  where tr.IsActive == "Y"
                                                  orderby tr.DisplayOrder ascending
                                                  select new CategoryDTO()
                                                  {
                                                      Id = tr.Id,
                                                      Name = tr.Name
                                                  };
        return List;
    }
    // GET: api/Default
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Default/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/Default
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/Default/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Default/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: did you decorate it with [HttpGet] ?

Comment: Yeah i did that and its working with that but i have seen in one of the project that it wasn't decorated with [HttpGet] but it was working..

Comment: need to see your code to debug this.

Comment: I recommend this article https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/using-http-methods-correctly-in-asp-net-web-api/  in the middle of it, the author explains how ASP.NET finds the default method for an action

Comment: Could you post the URL you entered to access your API?

Comment: thanks for such a prompt support guys @Win the url is http://localhost:xxxx/api/default/Category.. BTW i got the answer from Riyadh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using web api 2, then you can use Attribute Routing
Follow this url, I hope you will get your answer

Sample:

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
```

To know more detail follow this link
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

There is another way you can use custom methode by writing your own route in WebApiConfig.cs
you can found this detail in this link
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, Riyadh.. thanks for your suggestion i have one through the article but is it possible to use custom methods without decoration?

Comment: yes it is possible:

Follow this url
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Thanks man! you made my day.. Now i felt much more command on routing.. thumbs up!

Comment: I am happy that, my ans helps you.