# how can I customize the name of a request [HttpGet] in c #

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have created the following web service and can access it by:

```
https://localhost:44311/valores/1
```

but I want to access it with a url like:

```
https://localhost:44311/usuario/1
```

using `usuario` in the url

```
    [HttpGet("{id:int}",Name ="usuario")] 
    public ActionResult<Usuario> Get(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new prueba2Context())
        {
            var usuario = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (usuario == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(usuario);
        }
    }
```

I am new to `c#`, I appreciate if you indicate what I am doing wrong and how to correct it.

This is the structure of my folder.

[image]

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @Andy ASP.NET core

Comment: Gaaaaaa.  That alters the response then.  Note any nasties out there, I gave my answer before this was established.

Comment: One, I have to delete my answer, because it it asp.net-core.  2.  Please "tag" with asp.net core in the future any questions about asp.net-core (vs dot-net-framework). (3) I'm going to edit the tag here. (4)  Technically, this is a repeat question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843264/how-to-add-custom-methods-to-asp-net-webapi-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using ASP.NET Core. A typical endpoint will be set up like this:

```
[ApiController, Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ComputationController : ControllerBase
{
    // ...

    [HttpPost, Route("beginComputation")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted, Type = typeof(JobCreatedModel))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BeginComputation([FromBody] JobParametersModel obj)
    {
        return Accepted(
            await _queuedBackgroundService.PostWorkItemAsync(obj).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("computationStatus/{jobId}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(JobModel))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, Type = typeof(string))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetComputationResultAsync(string jobId)
    {
        var job = await _computationJobStatusService.GetJobAsync(jobId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if(job != null)
        {
            return Ok(job);
        }
        return NotFound($"Job with ID `{jobId}` not found");
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

The `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute is for documentation frameworks such as `Swagger`.

I always use the `[Route]` attribute to define the endpoint path.

In your case, I would set it up as so:

```
[HttpGet, Route("usuario/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Usuario))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IActionResult GetUser(int id)
{
    using (var db = new prueba2Context())
    {
        var usuario = await db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (usuario == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(usuario);
    }
}
```

Comment: @yavg -- Please look in to `async` and `await` ... this is blocking code. You want to be as asynchronous as possible with your endpoints

Comment: If it is 'perfect' then "Mark As Answer" so this question does not come up under "not answered yet" SOF query-filters.

Comment: @andy  so yes, good piont.  but ..   you want to by async if the whole chain can be async-await'erized.   see "turtle" talk : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UjIuerv.jpg   (I am following your suggestion to return this async) but,I dont know how to solve that problem. I am using entity framework and from the database I built my models

Comment: @yavg -- try changing it to `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`

Comment: friend thank you very much, I hope not to bother you. but in terms of performance or advantages, I don't see how it improves using `async`. No more lines of code can be executed below while there is an `await` then one way or another it would be something` synchronous`.

Comment: @yavg -- you aren't bothering me in the least. But, I would google the pattern. It is a complicated subject. Just know you do not want your I/O bound calls to block. That will cause all kinds of problems for you down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Is more common use "Route"

like that

```
`[Route("usuario")]
 public ActionResult<Usuario> Get(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new prueba2Context())
        {
            var usuario = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (usuario == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(usuario);
        }
    }
```

`